# List of Appendices in ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices

I am trying to add my List of Figures to my (ShareLaTeX) document, but it wont appear in my Table of Content. Here are my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty} 
\newpage

\section*{Abstract}
\addtocontents{toc}{~\hfill\textbf{Side}\par}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{}Forord}

\section*{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{}Sammendrag}

\newpage
\tableofcontents 

\listoffigures   
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{}Figures}

\listoftables      
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{}Tables}
\newpage

\pagenumbering{arabic} ´

%Several sections here

\newpage
\appendix
\section{Appendix A}
\subsection{Appendix name}

\end{document}
```

So, my goal is to get something like this:

[image]

I already have the Figures and Tables, but I will also want to have the List of Equations and Appendices. Any help?

Comment: How do you create your List of Equations and List of Appendices?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of how you create your contents tables, the following provides a means for insertion of ad-hoc content related to `\section`s within your document.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\newcommand{\setsectiontocentry}[1]{\def\sectiontocentry{#1}}
\let\oldsection\section
\makeatletter
\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{ s o m }{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {% \section*
      \oldsection*{#3}%
      \IfValueTF{#2}
        {\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{}#2}}% \section*[.]{..}
        {\@ifundefined{sectiontocentry}
           {\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{} #3}}%
           {\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{} \sectiontocentry}}%
         \let\sectiontocentry\relax
        }
        %{\addcontentsline\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{}%
           %\ifcsname sectiontocentry\endcsname
             %\sectiontocentry
           %\else
              %#3%
           %\fi 
         %}%
         %\let\sectiontocentry\relax
        %}% \section*{..}
    }
    {% \section
      \IfValueTF{#2}
        {\oldsection[#2]{#3}}% \section[.]{..}
        {\oldsection{#3}}% \section{..}
    }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\addtocontents{toc}{~\hfill\textbf{Side}\par}
\section*{Abstract}

\section*{Introduction}

\clearpage

\setsectiontocentry{ToC}
\tableofcontents

\setsectiontocentry{Figures}
\listoffigures

\listoftables

\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\section{First section}
\section{Second section}
\section*[THIRD SECTION]{Third section}
\section{Last section}

\clearpage
\appendix
\section{First appendix}
\section{Second appendix}

\end{document}
```

Fundamentally, `\section*` commands don't make it into the ToC, nor does it allow for using an *optional* argument under `\section*`. The above preamble setup redefines the way `\section` functions to allow for the starred version `\section*` to have an optional argument and also insert that content into the ToC.

This works if you have access to `\section`, which you do in general. However, when you call `\tableofcontents` (and the like), a `\section` call is made on your behalf. For that, I've defined `\setsectiontocentry{<section toc>}` that will grab and place the appropriate `<section toc>` entry. Hopefully this is visualized in the above example.